# jQuery append data to li's level

Tags: jquery, html, click, html-lists

I am looking for a way to append `$.post()`'s data response to the height of the `li` that invoked it.

I know it has been done, but I can't find anything to read about it. So, any ideas?

Scheme

- List item1
- List item2
- List item3, on click here :

  ```
                        * sublist item1
                        * sublist item2
                        * sublist item3
  ```
- List item4

### UPDATE

The only code I have is the working `$.post()` and I do a `console.log(data)` just to see the response.

Ok, I would like to achieve something like this: http://www.alistapart.com/d/horizdropdowns/horizontal.htm with the `$.post()`'s response

Comment: be bit more clear with some relevant piece of code

Comment: Do u mean u want to append data as li retrived from ajax ??

Comment: what do you mean by "to append $.post()'s data response to the height of the li that invoked it."

Comment: If I understood your question right, you want to append a `<ul></ul>` or a block of `html` in a `<li></li>`?

Comment: even with your updated description, the question is still unclear.
please, help us so we can help you.

Comment: Do you want to add another list to the *<li>* element that was clicked? Or do you want to apply the response to the height attribute of the *<li>* that was clicked?

Comment: I want to append some HTML that I build when the response is retrieved in `$.post()`. I want to add that response to the height of the li that invoked `$('li.clickable') .click(function(){...})`

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com/d/horizdropdowns/horizontal.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li.clickable').on('click', function() {
  var list = $(this);
  $.ajax({
      url: 'url_to_script',
      method: 'post',
      success: function(res) {

         var response = $(res); // assume that you response contains li tags i.e '<li>subitem 1</li>' and more
         list.append(response); // append response to list that clicked

         /* >> OR  << */
         // if you response contains data as array/field
         $.each(res, function(index, data) {
            list.append('<li>'+ data['some_text'] +'</li>'); // some_text is assumed property, you have something else
         });

        // ACCORDING TO YOUR COMMENT
        var sublist = '<ul>';
        $.each(res, function(index, data) {
            sublist += '<li>'+ data['some_text'] +'</li>'; // some_text is assumed property, you have something else
         });
            sublist += '</ul>'; // now sublist is like <ul><li>...</li>....</ul>
        list.append(sublist); // append the sublist to ul.clickable
      }
  });
});
```

**NOTE: You have to make some CSS to improve looks**

Comment: this just appends the response, I'm looking for an effect like: http://www.alistapart.com/d/horizdropdowns/horizontal.htm

Answer (score 1):

An idea on what it looks like....

```
 $('yourliclass').click(function(){
       //do ajax
       $.ajax({
        .......
        .......

        success:function(data){ //data needs to be in json format
           var htmlcontent = "";
        htmlcontent = '<ul>';
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        htmlcontent += '<li>'+data[i]['your_index']+'</li>';
    }
    htmlcontent += '</ul>';
        }
$(this).appendTo(htmlcontent);


});
```

}

Comment: I'm going to try this, this looks the closest for what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        var data;
        $(document).ready(function()
        {

            $(".list li").click(function()
            {
                $.post("filename.php",function(res)
                {
                     data="<li>"+res+"</li>";           
                });
                $(this).after(data);
            });
        });     

<body>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```